# Multiple get request parameters with @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Getting below error while calling request with multiple parameter in get request :  http://localhost:8080/find/1/empid/146220

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Aug 01 19:33:35 IST 2017 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Name for parameter binding
>   must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you need to use @Param for
>   named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure to compile with
>   -parameters.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! On JDKs < 8, you
>   need to use @Param for named parameters, on JDK 8 or better, be sure
>   to compile with -parameters.

Demo.java

```
@Entity
public class Demo {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    //getter -setter
}
```

DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private DemoRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/find/{id}/{name}/{value}")
    public Demo find(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String value){
        return repository.findByIdAndNameAndValue(id, name, value);
    }
}
```

DemoRepository.java

```
public interface DemoRepository extends CrudRepository<Demo, Long>{

    @Query("select d from Demo d where d.id = :id and d.name = :name and d.value = :value")
    Demo findByIdAndNameAndValue(Long id, String name, String value);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `PathVariable` names.

**Example:**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/find/{id}/{name}/{value}")
public Demo find(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id, @PathVariable(name = "name") String name, @PathVariable(name = "value") String value){
    return repository.findByIdAndNameAndValue(id, name, value);
}
```

And in your `Query` method as well

**Example:**

```
@Query("select d from Demo d where d.id = :id and d.name = :name and d.value = :value")
Demo findByIdAndNameAndValue(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("name") String name, @Param("value") String value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should change your query to:

```
 @Query("select d from Demo d where d.id = ?#{[0]} and d.name = ?#{[1]} and d.value = ?#{[2]}")
```